# Recursive function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, function

I need to determine a nth derivate of a given function using the code below, inspired in the recursive function.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{fp}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\newcommand{\ar}[1]{\fpeval{round(#1,5)}}
\newcommand{\f}{0.5\cos(2t+\pi)}%Para escrever em LaTeX o nome da função


\begin{document}


 \tikzset{fixed point arithmetic} 
 \tikzmath{
  real \xzero; 
  real \h;
  %
  \xzero = 0.4;
  \h = 0.0001;
  %
  function f(\x) {
      \y =  0.5*cos(deg(2*\x+pi));
  return \y; 
  };
  %
  function derivate(\x,\h) {
      \y =  (f(\x+\h)-f(\x-\h))/(2*\h);
  return \y; 
  };
  %
  function Nthderivate(\x,\h,\n) {
      if \n == 1 then {
         \d = derivate(\x,\h);}
         else {
         \d =  (Nhderivate(\x+\h,\h,\n-1) -  Nhderivate(\x-\h,\h,\n-1))/(2*\h); 
      };
  return \d; 
  };
  %
  \n=1;
  \dum = derivate(\xzero,\h);
  \n=2;
  \ddois = Nthderivate(\xzero,\h,\n);
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\node[above] (2) at (0,0)  {\parbox{15cm}{


Vamos determinar a derivada de $s(t)=\f$ no ponto $t_0=\xzero$ e com $h=\h$:
\\[0.5cm]
O valor da derivada primeira é:\\

$\displaystyle f'(\xzero) \approx \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0-h)}{2h} = \dum$\\

O valor da segunda derivada é:\\

$\displaystyle f''(\xzero) \approx \frac{f'(x_0+h)-f'(x_0-h)}{2h} = \ddois$
}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But, don't work.
I would like to use tikzmath.
Anyone can help me please?

Comment: note tikz is using _fixed_ point arithmetic to around 5 decimal places, not floating point, its numerical accuracy can't really be relied on for extensive chained calculations. `\fpeval` is floating point, and more accurate but you are not using that in your main calculation

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the comment.
But to the main question, do you have any solution?

Comment: you did not show the error which is `! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function \`Nhderivate'`  which looks like a typo to me `Nh` when it should be `Nth`

Answer (score 1):

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `Nhderivate'
```

If I correct the typo in the function name and remove the offending `\\`  it runs with no warnings:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{fp}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\newcommand{\ar}[1]{\fpeval{round(#1,5)}}
\newcommand{\f}{0.5\cos(2t+\pi)}%Para escrever em LaTeX o nome da função


\begin{document}


 \tikzset{fixed point arithmetic} 
 \tikzmath{
  real \xzero; 
  real \h;
  %
  \xzero = 0.4;
  \h = 0.0001;
  %
  function f(\x) {
      \y =  0.5*cos(deg(2*\x+pi));
  return \y; 
  };
  %
  function derivate(\x,\h) {
      \y =  (f(\x+\h)-f(\x-\h))/(2*\h);
  return \y; 
  };
  %
  function Nthderivate(\x,\h,\n) {
      if \n == 1 then {
         \d = derivate(\x,\h);}
         else {
         \d =  (Nthderivate(\x+\h,\h,\n-1) -  Nthderivate(\x-\h,\h,\n-1))/(2*\h); 
      };
  return \d; 
  };
  %
  \n=1;
  \dum = derivate(\xzero,\h);
  \n=2;
  \ddois = Nthderivate(\xzero,\h,\n);
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\node[above] (2) at (0,0)  {\parbox{15cm}{


Vamos determinar a derivada de $s(t)=\f$ no ponto $t_0=\xzero$ e com $h=\h$:
\\[0.5cm]
O valor da derivada primeira é:

$\displaystyle f'(\xzero) \approx \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0-h)}{2h} = \dum$

O valor da segunda derivada é:

$\displaystyle f''(\xzero) \approx \frac{f'(x_0+h)-f'(x_0-h)}{2h} = \ddois$
}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However tex fixed point arithmetic is designed for calculating a few font sizes, it is not numerically accurate to do intensive chained numerical approximations, so any outcome is more by luck than design.

[image]